# Access Domain through Browser Works but Ping to the same Domain Fails

Tags: linux, windows-server-2008, amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services, mac-osx-server

I want to know something *I can access a domain through browser and is working*. But when i tried a ping on that domain **Request Time Out** happens always

I thought i might have lost the internet connection or something wrong with ping but pinging other sites works!

Can something like that can be configured in server or domain control panel? so the ping to that domain doesn't works?

Please share your thoughts

Comment: Can you tell me what the OS of the DC your trying to ping is?

Comment: @nick-young  i don't know much details the OS but i will try to find out.

Comment: I know on our server 2012r2 boxes sometimes they don't respond to pings. You could attempt a traceroute to find out where the process stops.

Comment: Thanks, i did a trace route and its stops at x.y.64.16 and the actual ip is x.y.67.148 so does it means they are blocking pings? can we configure like that?

Comment: I would check if they are blocking pings. To me that is the most likely. It's common to prevent ping sweeps.

Comment: If your site works, why it is a problem that ping doesn't work? A failed ping is not necessarily an indication for a problem, as any host on the route including the target machine might just drop it. And also: Why are you spamming tags ("Linux", "mac-osx-server")?

Comment: Ping isn't a magical network test. As useful as it is, it's only a test of whether or not ping works when all's said and done.

Comment: Hmm, @sven so you think it is not relevant question? i just want to know whether it is possible to configure like and was curious thats it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ping uses ICMP, not TCP. ICMP has to be especially allowed through a firewall for ping to work, plus the server needs to be configured to respond to ping.

Given you've tagged AWS I guess that's where you're having your problem, even though you haven't said so in your question. Go into your EC2 security group, edit the inbound rules, add "All ICMP" to the list of types allowed in. Make sure the source is set to "anywhere" if that's what you want, or just your IP. If it's just your IP then the format is 1.2.3.4/32, and you can get your IP from [here](http://www.whatismyip.com). Your IP is probably dynamic and so will change occasionally, so if it stops responding to ping change the rule. You could use 1.2.0.0/16 to try to account for this. ICMP isn't particularly risky to let through a firewall AFAIK.

There may be additional steps required to make Windows respond to pings, I don't know for sure.

Comment: Welcome - hit the little green tick if you decide to accept my answer, or if you have problems with it post a comment and screenshots and I'll try to help.

Answer (score 2):

> [Ping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ping_%28networking_utility%29) operates by sending Internet Control Message Protocol (ICMP)
>   echo request packets to the target host and waiting for an ICMP echo
>   reply.

On the other hand, while [browsing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browsing) you are using in most cases the [HTTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertext_Transfer_Protocol) protocol to fetch data from the remote server. Other commonly used protocols are HTTPS, FTP etc.

As you can see, they are two different protocls, and one of them can be blocked or allowed using firewall rules, without affecting the other.

It is quite common that ping or ICMP is blocked by default for security reasons, and any decent firewall will keep everything closed anyway unless opened by the user.